# How to pass a Boolean parameter in cucumber with java?

Tags: java, cucumber

How can I pass a Boolean parameter in [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) with java? 
I hava the following method with a Boolean parameter:

```java
@Then("test if he is a admin")
public void verify_connect(boolean admin)
{
    if(admin)
        connectAsAdmin();
    else 
        connectAsUser();
}
```

Comment: Hi Lamya, welcome to SO! Please edit your question so that it becomes clear (a) what you already tried, (b) potential error messages, (c) that you did enough research on your own.

Comment: You can look into the following: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_java_testing

Comment: I have a project that has already realized and runs and I do not have the right to change the signatures of the methods, my role is to perform automated tests with cucumber

Comment: this is a method @Override public long getTotalCountSqlDynamic(List<Map<String, String>> criterias, AbstractUserBean connectedUser, boolean isAdmin) { Query q = null; if (connectedUser.isTypeSupplier()) { q = createSQLQuerySupplier(criterias, true, connectedUser.getUid(), isAdmin); } else { q = createSQLQuery(criterias, true, connectedUser, isAdmin); } BigInteger count = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult(); return count.longValue(); }

Answer (score 13):

Use `@ParameterType`
https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

```
@ParameterType(value = "true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE")
public Boolean booleanValue(String value) {
    return Boolean.valueOf(value);
}

@Then("Something is set to {booleanValue}")
public void somethingIsSetTo(Boolean value) {

}
```

Comment: Documentation on cucumber-expressions has moved to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#readme

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to convert the string "admin" to a boolean value, however you can parameterize the kind of user by creating a back reference in the regular expression using parentheses:

```java
@Then("test if he is a (admin|user)")
public void verify_connect(String userType) {
    if (userType == "admin")
        connectAsAdmin();
    else 
        connectAsUser();
}
```

Comment: I have a project that has already realized and runs and I do not have the right to change the signatures of the methods, my role is to perform automated tests with cucumber

Comment: this is a method  @Override
 public long getTotalCountSqlDynamic(List<Map<String, String>> criterias, AbstractUserBean connectedUser,
   boolean isAdmin) {

  Query q = null;
  if (connectedUser.isTypeSupplier()) {
   q = createSQLQuerySupplier(criterias, true, connectedUser.getUid(), isAdmin);
  } else {
   q = createSQLQuery(criterias, true, connectedUser, isAdmin);
  }
        
  BigInteger count = (BigInteger) q.getSingleResult();
  return count.longValue();
  
 }

Comment: @LamyaMessaoudi: Why can't you change the signatures of the step definitions? I can understand not changing method signatures for the application itself, but being unable to change step definition method signatures seems to be an unnecessary constraint, and I would question that. You should be able to change the step definition signatures. Just run the tests.